# How do i integrate Azure IoT in my Ionic Project?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-suite

I am Using Azure IoT Hub, which is Connected with Rasberry Pi.
Rasberry Pi device sending data to my AzureIoT hub.

My Question is , How to access the Azure IoT hub data in to my Cordova Project ?.
here , I am using AngularJs , Cordova, Ionic Framework for implement Hybrid Mobile Apps for IOS and Android.
I have found the C# SDK, JavaSdk and Objective-C SDK. Please remember i am not using native development.

Thanks,

Comment: What exact things do you want? And what problems you have encountered?

Comment: I want to show IoT device data into Phone using Cordova Platform.

Comment: Azure IoT sdk has node.js support, you can consider integrating that code into your cordova project.

Answer (score 1):

> My Question is , How to access the Azure IoT hub data in to my Cordova Project?

The fastest way to achieve that is to consume the [Iot Hub Rest API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt548492.aspx) in your cordova project using [HttpWebRequest(Ajax)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

AngularJS has a great wrapper [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for Ajax. You can leverage it.